# Count appearance of string in a comma-separated data column from another table

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I'm having an issue trying to corrently display the count of occurrences in a column fom a different table. I have a table all products:

Product

act_checking

act_savings

act_auto

I need to find the count of each of those located in another table's column that has those products in comma-separated values:

M0_List

act_checking,act_savings,act_auto

act_auto,act_checking

Desired result:

act_checking  2

act_savings    1

act_auto         2

I am using this measure but in the results I get an extra row with blank values with a count, showing an incorrect count

```
VAR _name = 
    MAX(Products[Product])

RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(Query1),
        CONTAINSSTRING(Query1[M0_LIST], _name)
    )
```

act_checking  2

(blank)       3

act_savings   1

act_auto      2

What I found is that this measure is not counting any values after the first comma (",") and am struggling to find the correct measure to count all values.

Much appreciated in advance!

VAR _name =
MAX(Products[Product])

RETURN
CALCULATE(
COUNTROWS(Query1),
CONTAINSSTRING(Query1[M0_LIST], _name)
)

But this measure is only counting the first string and not strings after a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this measure:

```
=
VAR ThisProduct =
    MIN( Products[Product] )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS( FILTER( Query1, SEARCH( ThisProduct, Query1[M0_List],, 0 ) > 0 ) )
```

Comment: Thanks @Jos, I just tried with this measure but I the same results, a lower total count plus an extra "blank" product row with a count. I checked and it still doesn't count any values after the comma, and both columns are formatted as text, all strings are trimmed and there are no spaces in between commas (e.g.: checking,savings,etc)

Comment: I can only go with the data you posted, for which the results are as you expected. Suggest you also test using the precise data you posted. I'm guessing there's something about your actual data that you're not sharing which is making the difference.

Comment: Thanks @Jos. 
Table Products is just one column that contains one product per cell (e.g., cc_checking, cc_savings, and so on). 
Table M0 contains a column in which each cell can contain either just one string (e.g., cc_checking) or have several strings separated by a comma with no spaces (e.g., cc_checking,cc_savings,cc_auto). 
I can have the result in either a new column in the Products table or a measure (preferably). Hope this gives more context and thanks for taking your time.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. For the data you posted my solution works, as I'm sure you can verify yourself. Post some amended data for which my solution doesn't work.