# Count appearance of string in a comma-separated data column does not count values after the first comma

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have two tables:

**Products** table has a single column with one product per field

**List** table has several columns but the column I'm interested in has fields that can have as little as one product to as much as 17, all separated with a comma and no spaces in between

The issue I'm facing and need help with is to correctly count each product either, ideally as as a measure. I tried two measures but they both gave me an incorrect count of blanks; there are no blank values either table.
What I found is that both measures count only the *first* value they find in the List column and then continue counting subsequent rows:

[Measures used and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0d1s.png)

How can I correctly count all values in each field from the List table and have zero "blank" counts?

Thanks!

Comment: Please paste your data as copiable text. Thanks

Comment: How does this differ from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75619088/count-appearance-of-string-in-a-comma-separated-data-column-from-another-table)?

Comment: Hi @David, data is now as copiable text, thanks.

Comment: Hi @Jos, thanks for the reply. Your suggestions worked with the sample data I provided. I then used that measure with my real data and still have a blank count as you can see in the screenshot I provided. 
I'm now using my real data as example hoping to get the accurate count that I'm not getting. I know the issue is that the measures are only counting the first value they find before the comma and then it goes on to the next row.

Comment: You need to come up with a reduced, copiable dataset that demonstrates your issue. Screenshots which relate to thousands of rows' worth of data are not much help, I'm afraid.

Comment: The first measure is wrong, because it returns 0 for not found and then you're comparing it to >= 0. The second measure (commented) seems correct. This is not a measure issue but data issue. You have blanks in your product table or have a bad active relationship.

Comment: @Jos I have pasted more rows for more tables, let me know if this works.

Comment: Hi @Joao, thanks for the input. I have checked and yes the table with the comma-separated fields has blank rows, if there a way I filter out blank rows? 

Also for the active relationship I see that the Products table is connected to the List table in a one to many relationship on that same column.

Comment: The issue is the second one. Either delete the relationship or add the following in your calculate: `CROSSFILTER ( table1[column], table2[column], NONE )` (replace with the actual columns the relationship is using

Comment: @Joao, thank you very much, that was it! As soon as I removed the relationship I was able to see the correct counts. I don't know how to flag your comment as "solved", let me know if it matters. Thanks again and have a nice day.

Comment: Alternatively, you could create a derived table in Power Query, using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-expandlistcolumn. Then you get a clean table where each value is on a separate row.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.